# I want to grep "exonic" in my ".tsv" file provided that column 13 of this file contains "p."

Tags: text-processing, bioinformatics

I want to grep `exonic` in my `.tsv` file provided that column 13 of this file contains `p.`.

Can you help me with the code I need?

Note: As there are also exonic variants with no amino acid changes, I want to filter exonic variants whose amino acid changes are mentioned in column 13.

- `p.` stands for amino acid change and the example is

  ```
  CD24:uc004ftz.1:exon1:c.A130T:p.T44S
  ```
- `p.` is common for all variants with amino acid changes.

This is an example:

```
hrY 21154569 21154569 A G PASS hom exonic CD24 . synonymous SNV CD24:NM_001291737:exon1:c.T27C:p.L9L,CD24:NM_001359084:exon1:c.T27C:p.L9L,CD24:NM_013230:exon1:c.T27C:p.L9L,CD24:NM_001291738:exon2:c.T27C:p.L9L
```

In the newly annotated `.tsv` file, we have sometimes 3 different definitions for each variant in different columns. For example, a variant can be defined as exonic, UTR, and intronic at the same time (based on different databases used).

I am to filter the true exonic variants, as some exonic variants do not have an amino acid change (`p.*`)

Comment: Thank you for the example, but please have a look at the other requests for clarification: What do you want to print - the entire line, or only one field (if so, which)? In your example, column 13 consists of `,`-separated fields which in turn consist of `:`-separated fields, of which the last one may start with `p.` - which is the "relevant" location to look tor `p.`? Any of these comma-separated fields, or only a particular one? Can the `p.` only occur at the beginning of the last `:`-separated parts of such a field?

Comment: Also, please note that not everyone here is a bioinformatics specialist (although there are quite a few around), so make sure to use terminology that a layman can understand, too. In this case, it means you are kindly requested to provide "border cases" which the filtering algorithm needs to handle correctly, hence the need for "desired output".

Comment: When I use this command >>>  grep -w exonic fileName_or_filePath , I receive lots of chromosome variants that are not exonic indeed, because true exonic variants have amino acid changes at the beginning of the last :-separated parts of column 13. I need a code to get only true exonic variants with p.* (protein) change.

Comment: chr9    138507244       138507244       A       G       PASS    het     exonic  LOC102723971    .     unknown  UNKNOWN intergenic      LOC100130954;GLT6D1     dist=28286;dist=8258    .       .       ncRNA_exonic   ENSG00000236543 .                                Here is an example. This is an exonic variant bu t doesn't have a protein change.

Comment: As mentioned before, please also postthe example in your question, and indicate what the desired output should be (for that example line, nothing, of course, but for the other example line, do you need the entire line or only parts of it?)

Comment: Fatima, first of all, please ***[edit]*** your question and add the clarifications there. So, please [edit] your question and add more example lines and then show us the exact output you expect from that example. Make sure to include lines that should be removed as well as lines that should be kept. Note that the example you gave us has no protein change, it's a synonymous variant.

Comment: Regarding [your comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/686975/i-want-to-grep-exonic-in-my-tsv-file-provided-that-column-13-of-this-file-c#comment1298654_686975) - the people who understand what an "exonic variant" or "amino acid change" are aren;t necessarily the same people who know the best way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -ne '.put if .words[12].match("p.") && .match("exonic") ;'
```

Sample Input:

```
hrY 21154569    21154569    A   G   PASS    hom exonic  CD24    .   synonymous  SNV CD24:NM_001291737:exon1:c.T27C:p.L9L,CD24:NM_001359084:exon1:c.T27C:p.L9L,CD24:NM_013230:exon1:c.T27C:p.L9L,CD24:NM_001291738:exon2:c.T27C:p.L9L
hrY 21154569    21154569    A   G   PASS    hom exonic  CD24    .   synonymous  SNV CD24:NM_001291737:exon1:c.T27C:q.L9L,CD24:NM_001359084:exon1:c.T27C:q.L9L,CD24:NM_013230:exon1:c.T27C:q.L9L,CD24:NM_001291738:exon2:c.T27C:q.L9L
hrY 21154569    21154569    A   G   PASS    hom intronic    CD24    .   synonymous  SNV CD24:NM_001291737:exon1:c.T27C:p.L9L,CD24:NM_001359084:exon1:c.T27C:p.L9L,CD24:NM_013230:exon1:c.T27C:p.L9L,CD24:NM_001291738:exon2:c.T27C:p.L9L
```

Sample Output:

```
hrY 21154569    21154569    A   G   PASS    hom exonic  CD24    .   synonymous  SNV CD24:NM_001291737:exon1:c.T27C:p.L9L,CD24:NM_001359084:exon1:c.T27C:p.L9L,CD24:NM_013230:exon1:c.T27C:p.L9L,CD24:NM_001291738:exon2:c.T27C:p.L9L
```

Above is an answer coded in **Raku**, a member of the Perl family of programming languages. The Perl6 project was initiated in year 2000, with the name of the language changed from Perl6  to Raku in 2019. Briefly, a test input file is created using:

1. your authentic tsv text as line #1;
2. line #2 substitutes "`q.`" in place of "`p.`"
3. line #3 of the test input file substitutes the word "`intronic`" in place of the word "`exonic`";

The Raku code above searches for lines that `match` a literal "`p.`" in the 12th column (index_0 locates the 13th column at `.words[12]`). If there is also a `match` to the word "`exonic`", the line is returned. The `&&` (short-circuiting AND operator) immediately skips the line if the first (i.e. left, "`p.`") conditional evaluates to `False`.

Note, you could use Raku's `grep` routine, if you're comfortable writing regexes.

https://docs.raku.org/routine/match
https://docs.raku.org/routine/grep
https://raku.org